# Python / Oracle Insert Statement

Tags: python, oracle, insert

being fairly new at Python, looking for some help on why this INSERT statement is not working:

```
<pre>
v_history_seq = curs1.callfunc('GET_NEXT_SEQUENCE', int, ['upload_history_seq'])
v_upload_date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

v_insert = ("""\
  INSERT INTO upload_history (sequence, upload_date, editor, broker, filename, orig_filename, file_type,
                              account_type_id, upload_type, quarter, quarter_year, user_notes_id)
  VALUES (:sequence, TO_DATE(:upload_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), :editor, :broker, :filename, :orig_filename, :file_type,
          :account_type_id, :upload_type, :quarter, :quarter_year, :user_notes_id)""")

try:
  curs1.execute(v_insert,
                sequence        = v_history_seq,
                upload_date     = v_upload_date,
                editor          = p_editor,
                broker          = p_broker,
                filename        = file_list[x][0],
                orig_filename   = file_list[x][1],
                file_type       = p_upload_type,
                account_type_id = p_account_type,
                upload_type     = p_upload_type,
                quarter         = p_quarter,
                quarter_year    = p_year,
                user_notes_seq  = p_user_notes_seq)

except cx.Oracle.Error as err:
  error, = err.args
  logging.info("  Error inserting into Upload History: " + error.code)
  logging.info("  Error inserting into Upload History: " + error.message)
</pre>
```

Any help would be great, and thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Getting the sequence and then running the query is two round-trips (minimum).  Do you really need to call a PL/SQL procedure to get the sequence number or can you just use something like `upload_history_seq.nextval` in the INSERT statement?  Or just wrap the function call and the INSERT in an anonymous PL/SQL block.

Comment: Also replace your upload_date construction with "sysdate" so you don't have to worry about the to_date conversion.